# Scheduled-Trigger Flow only updating first record

Tags: visual-workflow, httprequest, pricebook, scheduled

I am having an issue with a simple Scheduled Trigger Flow. It is my understanding that a flow of this type should be able to update a batch of records at once without requiring a loop to facilitate that action.

What I am finding is that for some reason, this flow is only updating the first record and no more.

Here is how I have my flow setup:

[image: Flow Diagram]

There is an HTTP Get action to pull an updated value for currencies from https://currencylayer.com/.

I have tried two ways. One is storing that value into a variable and updating the record with that value, or directly assigning the value to the record itself. For whatever reason, neither way seems to really effect the end result.

In debug mode it will follow the correct path and it claims it will update the records after the interview is finished. With that being said, the first record DOES update - but no other records in the batch do.

[image: Filter]

Here is how I have my records filtered. All of them that I am trying to update ARE active.

And here is how I have my update records setup:
[image: Update]

Any suggestions, or comments as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

For some additional information, here is my debug log:

[image: debug log]

Comment: in debug mode, only one record of the batch is processed

Comment: @cropredy, yes that is correct - but when I set the flow to active and schedule the start for say 15minutes in the future it does not update the other records.

Comment: (1) check the debug log for the scheduled flow, you may have an exception; (2) is the action bulkified? (that is, it returns results for each flow interview? - it will only be called once for the entire transaction of n=200 records)

Comment: @cropredy I will have to check on the debug log. As far as the action being bulkified I'm not sure how to even check that. Would that mean each flow interview would cause an API call to be used? I don't really want to do that. If that is how I would need to accomplish that - i wonder if it would be better to launch a subflow to update the records and only have the schdudled trigger flow grab the new value from the API.